# How to upload map xml file to server?

Tags: android, dictionary, server, openstreetmap

I want to build map and display it on Android phone. Firstly I'm dealing with the map of the program Josm and getting the XML file. Secondly, I need to upload it to the server. (I cant do this updating part)

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: `i cant do this step`. Please explain why not. What's exactly your problem?

Comment: Uploading is done by using the [editing API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API). So where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: @greenapps 
the problem is : after  editing  the map with josm and get the xml file,i want to up load it into server 
I dont know how to upload it to server

Comment: Yes that you already told. That i already understood. So now read again what i wanted to know. And answer scai too.